# Is it possible to force a Maven plugin to be included in a project from a dependency of that project?

Tags: maven

I have three Java projects. The first is an application, `com.foo:foo-application:1.0.0`, and the second is a module used as a dependency to that application, `com.foo:foo-framework:1.0.0`. The third is a Maven plugin authored by our team, `com.foo:foo-plugin:1.0.0`.

My intention is that any project, e.g. `foo-application`, which uses classes available in `foo-framework` must also validate that it has used those classes correctly, where said validation is enforced by `foo-plugin`.

Is there a way to enforce this behaviour within `foo-framework`'s POM.xml, whereby any Maven module which declares it as a dependency in its own POM will have `foo-plugin` executed as part of its build lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

No (at least no way that I'm aware of).

when you declare a dependency on something, youre declaring a dependency on its output artifacts (and transitively their dependencies as optionally described in that artifact's pom.xml file). There's no place in [a pom file](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_DependencyManagement) to force anything on the build importing it - the build importing it may not even be a maven build.

it appears you may be able to do something similar via other tools though - for example checkstyle supports [discovering rules from dependencies on the classpath](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues/400) (not exactly what you want and depends on users of your library running checkstyle configured just right)